# Development Server is not auto refreshing while making changes to a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am beginner learning React. I am having a problem when I delete all the boilerplate files except index.js in order to start from scratch.

I create my first "hello world" component and then start the dev server. The browser opens up and shows my component but when I change "hello world" to "hello people" the component displayed in browser is still "hello world" and I have to refresh the browser to show "hello people".

There is no any error showing in console. The only thing that is in the console is `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...`

I am a beginner and did a lot of searching on how to fix this but I couldn't solve it. Please suggest something that may fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to config webpack to watch your changes

in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  watch: true
};
```

you can refer to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/ for more details.

Comment: Shall i write this code in my existing js file or is there an existing file called webpack.config.js ?

Comment: UPDATE: when I have App.js and index.js files in my src folder, and I use App.js to create component and export it and in index.js I import and render the App.js and when I make changes to component in App.js, the browser refreshes fine and displays the updated code. So the problem is only when I have index.js in src folder.

Comment: can you share the index.js file and package.json